# Unable to convert object to double

Tags: c#

When inserting a new student into the database, their GPA is not entered, so when I call an event handler to display the GPA, it crashes.

```
object value;    
sql = string.Format("SELECT ROUND(AVG(CAST(Rating AS Float)), 4) FROM GPA WHERE StudentID={0};;", StudentID);
value = this.datatier.ExecuteScalarQuery(sql);

double avgGPA;
if (value != null)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("null");
    avgGPA = Convert.ToDouble(value);
}
else avgGPA = 0.0;
```

I tried this fix, where I make sure `value!=null` before I `Convert.ToDouble()`, but I am crashing regardless, particularly on this line:

```
avgGPA = Convert.ToDouble(value);
```

with error: *Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.*

My question is how do I assign a default value, like 0.0, so that the program doesn't crash when a GPA isn't found?

EDIT: Everyone was spot on on the solution, thanks to all! The new question becomes, is DBNull always the null of a database query?

Comment: change to if(value != DbNull.Value)

Comment: also, I wouldn't set the gpa to 0 when you don't find it. make it nullable or something

Comment: No one uses `value is DBNull` #sadpanda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check if it's [DBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.dbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
avgGPA = value == DBNull.Value ? 0D : Convert.ToDouble(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

In query check if null return default value using `isnull()`:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(CAST(isnull(Rating,0) AS Float)), 4)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still be null if there are no rows?

Comment: in current case record will be available for sure

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on either side, whichever makes the most sense given your circumstance:

```
-- In the query, return zero if null
select isnull(ROUND(AVG(CAST(Rating AS Float)), 4), 0.0) from...
```

Or

```
// In the code, check for DBNull
if (value != DBNull.Value)
{
    avgGPA = Convert.ToDouble(value);
}
```

Comment: current query will always return record

Comment: Yes, this one will return 0 because the `isnull` is wrapped around an aggregate of data. If you just did `isnull(Rating, 0)` and your query returned no records, then `value` would actually be `null`, not `DBNull`, since the query would have returned no records at all. If you did `isnull` on the Rating instead of on the average and had no records, then you'd get `DBNull`. But `isnull` on `avg` means that if `avg` ends up as null for whatever reason, you'll still be able to convert that to zero in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
double avgGPA = Convert.IsDBNull(value) ? 0.0 : Convert.ToDouble(value);
```